# Inserting multiple data tables from stored procedure into strongly typed/named dataset

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqldataadapter

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that returns several tables. I am accessing these in VB via a data adapter with table mapping in the following method:

```
da.SelectCommand = sqlCommand
da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "SettingsTable")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "MainDataTable")

da.Fill(dsResult)
```

The issue I have here is around the source table name. These automatically generate as Table, Table1, Table2 etc.  Is there any way I can give these tables names coming out of the stored procedure? Depending on parameters I may not return all tables every time, so sometimes the table I map to "MainDataTable" will be "Table1", and sometimes "Table2".

Are there any solutions for this? I need to keep compatibility back as far as SQL Server 2008 R2 if possible.

Many thanks in advance.